# jQuery, Check for Change Before Submit, Form with Multiple Rows

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form that is dynamically loaded from a query with multiple rows of form fields. I'd like to check for change on each row so that I am only submitting the changed rows. This is desirable because it is more information for me to process than the server can handle if I submit all rows.  I'm not sure how to use serialize and 'changed' to do that.  I'd like to only process those rows whose form fields have changed and ignore the rest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221633/select-submit-only-changed-form-fields-with-jquery

Comment: You probably do not want to use `.change()` for that. `.change()` triggers every time you do any kind of change -- what you want is to check what has changed since loading.

Comment: As pingul said use `.change()` to add a name to the form input.

But why not use PHP to check if the form field is empty when the user submits?